# When unchecking checkbox output value stays same. How can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function diagnose() {
  var add = 0;
  var age = parseFloat(document.getElementById('myNumber').value);
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('addon');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      add += parseFloat(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
  }
  var p = +add;
  var ad = 0;
  var checkboxe = document.getElementsByClassName('addon2');
  if (age < 3 && p >= 4) {

    for (var j = 0; j < checkboxe.length; j++) {
      if (checkboxe[j].checked) {
        ad += parseFloat(checkboxe[j].value);
      }
      var a = p + ad;

      if (a >= 5) {
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Clininacal diagnosis yes ";
      }
    }

  } else {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = " Clininacal diagnosis no";
  }
}
document.getElementById('table').addEventListener('change', diagnose);
```

```html
</head>
<body>
  Age: <input type="number" id="myNumber" class="no-spinners">
  <div id="table">
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46125218/edit#  <input type="checkbox" name="Neonatal" value="1.0" class="addon">
  <label for="Neo">Neo</label></br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="F" value="1.0" class="addon">
  <label for="Feed">Feed</label></br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="W" value="1.0" class="addon">
  <label for="Weight">Weight</label></br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Dysmorphic" value="1.0" class="addon">
  <label for="Char">Char</label></br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Pub" value="1.0" class="addon">
  <label for="Pub">Smally</label></br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="Dev" value="1.0" class="addon">
  <label for="Dev">Dev</label></br>
<hr>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Lethargy" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="Lethargy">Lethargy</label></br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Typical" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="TypicalBehavior">Typical</label></br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Sleep" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="Sleep">Sleep</label></br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Short" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="Short">Short</label></br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Hypo" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="Hypo">Hypo</label></br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Small" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="Small">Small</label></br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Narrow" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="Narrow">Narrow</label></br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Esot" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="Esot">Esot</label></br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Thick" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="Thick">Thick</label></br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Speech" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="Speech">Speech</label></br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="Skin" value=".5" class="addon2">
    <label for="Skin">Skin</label></br>
</div>
<span id="total"></span>

  </div>


</body>
```

So I have this code. Above the line each input has 1 point, under the line each input has .5 point. For right result It needs at least 5 points , but 4 of them must be from 1 point inputs. For example, four 1 point and two .5 point. I got It worked, but when unchecking the checkboxes It still shows the same string. So how can I fix it ? 
Thanks.

Comment: `ad += parseFloat(checkboxe[i].value);` is a typo, the index should be `j` as that is your current iterator. Voting to close.

Comment: I changed it, but It doesn't work.

Comment: Works when I try.

Comment: When It has 4.5 and 4 point It still shows "Clinical diagnosis yes" instead of "Clinical diagnosis no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just needed to add the `else` on the inner conditional evaluation as well.
The else:

```
else {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = " Clininacal diagnosis no";
}
```

The whole code:

```
function diagnose() {
    var add = 0;
    var age = parseFloat(document.getElementById('myNumber').value);
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('addon');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            add += parseFloat(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
    }
    var p = +add;
    var ad = 0;
    var checkboxe = document.getElementsByClassName('addon2');
    if (age < 3 && p >= 4) {    
        for (var j = 0; j < checkboxe.length; j++) {
            if (checkboxe[j].checked) {
                ad += parseFloat(checkboxe[j].value);
            }
            var a = p + ad;
            if (a >= 5) {
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Clininacal diagnosis yes ";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = " Clininacal diagnosis no";
            }
        }  
    } else {
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = " Clininacal diagnosis no";
    }
}
document.getElementById('table').addEventListener('change', diagnose);
```

Answer (score 0):

The last `else` block stating the negative answer is reached only when the `(age < 3 && p >= 4)` condition is not met, so when the positive answer was already reached there's no way to rewrite it - quick and dirty solution is to duplicate the last else after the `(a >= 5)` condition or store results in a variable and decide the resulting message according to it:

```
  var positive = false;
  if (age < 3 && p >= 4) {

    for (var j = 0; j < checkboxe.length; j++) {
      if (checkboxe[j].checked) {
        ad += parseFloat(checkboxe[j].value);
      }
      var a = p + ad;

      if (a >= 5) {
        positive = true;
      }  
    }

  }

  if (positive) {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Clininacal diagnosis yes ";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = " Clininacal diagnosis no";
  }
```